# Deleted Team Site Owners - group now can't recreate - name in use

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online

I accidentally deleted the group Team Site Owners from my site 'Technology'.

Now I want to recreate it with the same name, so it fits with the names of all the other default groups in all the other sites, but I get the message **The specified name is already in use**.

What are my options? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you navigate to <>/_layouts/permsetup.aspx, you'll be taken to the Group Set-Up screen.

In the Owners section, use an existing group and see if you can find the Team Site Owners group in there.  If so, select it and press OK.  This should restore the group.

What's happened is that the site has removed the user group but it has't been deleted via the root site.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get it back how it should be that way. No underscore at the start of _permsetup.aspx though.