# Identify who has removed usergroups from website

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, logging, access-rights

is it possible to identify who has removed Usergroups from a Web?

If it is not possible, what is the best way to track the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you have Site Collection Audit Logging enabled (Site Actions ->
>   Site Settings -> Configure audit log settings,) which hopefully you
>   do, you can view the Audit reports for the site. It will show the
>   group deletion under "Security Settings"

Since you are using SharePoint foundation you might want to check it through this way,

> Another option would be to check the IIS logs (configured in Central
>   Admin -> Operations -> Usage Analysis Processing, will also tell you
>   where they are stored if enabled).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330005/sharepoint-2007-determine-who-deleted-a-group

some people face problems re-creating deleted groups so follow this post if you do,

[Deleted Team Site Owners - group now can't recreate - name in use](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60834/deleted-team-site-owners-group-now-cant-recreate-name-in-use)